# angularjs: allow only integer in html input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<md-input-container flex>
  <label>{{'COMMON.AMOUNT' | translate }}</label>
  <input class="margin-top-2" id="depositpaidamount" enterastab name="disabledamount" type="number" ng-model="deposit.paidamount" ng-disabled="true" />
</md-input-container>
```

This field allows to enter decimal also. But i want to enter only integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onkeypress event in your input box

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode <= 31'>
```

Comment: This is not correct answer. User can enter `dot` which should not be.

Comment: i edited my answer jst removing 46 key code, try again

Comment: **But this will not work if user do copy-paste. User can not enter non-integer from keyboard BUT can paste**

Comment: use - ** onpaste="return false" **

Comment: `onpaste="return false"` is not good option. **What if user want to paste a valid integer?**

Comment: i think its better to use [jquery] (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/863397/jquery-Copy-Paste-Number-only-Validator)

Comment: No, we can do it using JavaScript only as well. Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a check in JavaScript Controller for this if entered value is a integer or not.

Below is working code:

```js
var invalidChars = ["-","+","e","."];

depositpaidamount.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (invalidChars.includes(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<md-input-container flex>
  <label>{{'COMMON.AMOUNT' | translate }}</label>
  <input class="margin-top-2" id="depositpaidamount" enterastab name="disabledamount" type="number" ng-model="deposit.paidamount" ng-disabled="true" />
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Is there any option to do only in html

Comment: @SrividhyaS you need to take care of for case of copy-paste as well. This code will prevent user to enter non-integer from keyboard as well as from copy-paste. Tester will raise a bug for this, so Keep in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Directive

```
app.directive('restrictTo', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var re = RegExp(attrs.restrictTo);
        var exclude = /Backspace|Enter|Tab|Delete|Del|ArrowUp|Up|ArrowDown|Down|ArrowLeft|Left|ArrowRight|Right/;

        element[0].addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            if (!exclude.test(event.key) && !re.test(event.key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
}
});

And In HTML we use following way:
<input type="text" restrict-to="[0-9]"/>
```

> See the Plunker Example HERE.. Visit: https://plnkr.co/edit/PVjVgKOqZWojDJUYxKt4?p=preview

If useful to you please mark it as answer.

Comment: @ShrividyaS - my example above will take care of copy-paste issue as well.